# Unable to locate element ,Will selenium 2.39 support DOJO Application?

Tags: jquery, html, selenium, dojo

I am trying to Automate a webpage using selenium 2.39 version.
Issue is i am not able to click the "plus and minus" control. I am getting following error :-

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='dijit__TreeNode_1']/div[1]/img"}
Command duration or timeout: 31.12 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

I tried by giving the default xpath and also created unique xpath but nothing worked ,I tried the following

1)//*[@id='dijit__TreeNode_1']/div[1]/img => (default)
2)//img[@src='Dojo/dojo/resources/blank.gif'][@data-dojo-attach-point='expandNode']
3)//img[@src='Dojo/dojo/resources/blank.gif'][@role='presentation'][@class='dijitTreeExpando dijitTreeExpandoOpened'][@data-dojo-attach-point='expandoNode']

I am just copying that part of HTML contents

-

can anyone please suggest any other Alternative.
I am also seeing few attributes like "data-dojo-attach-event" in the HTML content,Is the element not detected in selenium since its a Dojo application ??
Please share your feedbacks

Answer (score 1):

I've tested several Dojo webapps using Selenium without a problem so far. Selenium should work independently of the front-end framework, but you have to use it correctly.

Some things that might be checked first:

1. Are you waiting for the page to load and the widgets to be parsed?
2. Does the given XPath selector work when used in a browser? I usually use the Google Chrome developer tools to find out the XPath (by right clicking a DOM node you can choose to copy the XPath). There's also a plugin for Firebug to look for a DOM node by an XPath query if I recall correctly.

If you're not seeing many Dojo attributes, then the first point might be the issue. When the page isn't loaded + parsed, then it won't be able to find the DOM nodes (however it should be able to find them in half a minute I suppose).

For example, to wait for an element (using `WebDriver`) to load you could use:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myId")));
```

Comment: Indeed, I do that as well, but I also wait for a specific element to be loaded. I edited my answer with something else I do as well. Also make sure the XPath is correct. You could also try to increase the amount of time between your steps, that way it's easier to verify what's happening in your browser.

Comment: 1)I have given timeout like this in my code , so i think Page loading is not an issue.
2)The default xpath shown in firebug for the element i have selected is shown as something else in XPATH checker.like my xpath id for "plus and minus control" is "//*[@id='dijit__TreeNode_1']/div[1]/img" but the same id is when checked in XPATH checker is shown as "1".
so any suggestions